# Java Web Services, is it really that complex?

Tags: java, web-services

I am reading Java WebServices Up and Running, it sounds so complex with so much information.  I created couple of web services using eclipse IDE, which is so simple.  In real enterprise scenario, what is the usual approach to develop web service?  Of Course, it is different for different companies, but what is the most common approach.  I am more interested in the webservices in the middleware.

Comment: Your question is very broad. Are you asking for a tutorial on building web services?

Comment: Yes, too broad.  But no, generally speaking, setting up a Java-based web-service is not "that complex".

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether you mean SOAP services or REST.

REST is merely HTTP; you can implement them with servlets.

Spring web services makes SOAP web services pretty easy, but you have to have a WSDL.

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned Java Web Services Up and Running, I am still reading chapter 3.  It sounds complex for the chapters I have read so far.  When I created webservices using eclipse, it is very simple.  I just want to make sure with experts, should i continue read that book or any other reference book.  Also any recommendations on how to create a WSDL?  Not from Java class.  Any tools to create WSDL?  Thanks,

Comment: I don't know that book, so I can't comment.  It's not that complex.  Maybe you need to mull it over for awhile.  If you use Spring "contract first" web services, it'll generate the WSDL from your request and response XSD.  Don't ask for a tool to read your mind about the XSD - you have to do something from scratch.